# Configure Local Mail on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, email, mutt

My cron jobs are trying to mail their results using the local mail feature of Ubuntu (not internet email, the kind of mail you can read with mutt).  However, /var/log/syslog reports

/USR/SBIN/CRON[19212]: (speedtax) MAIL (mailed 52 bytes of output but got status 0x0006 )

I would like to setup local mail (so that cron can deliver the output successfully) but do not want to setup internet email.  Everything I find on google is about the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install postfix` (or if you really must, `sendmail`). Then you can configure your `/etc/aliases` (and run `sudo newaliases` after that) to redirect mail from e.g. `root` wherever you want - *including* an internet email address, but by default Ubuntu sets it as the user who installed the system.